# Image spectrum computation

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to find the spectrum of an image `F'` such that:

```
F' = F(u,v) T(u,v)
```

where

```
T(u,v) = (sqrt(u^2+v^2))^p
```

---

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
f = fft2(I);
F = fftshift(f);
```

My questions are:

1. How can I implement `T(u,v)`? What would be `u` and `v`  where `p=2`?
2. How to get `F'`, what is the suitable command to do this convolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check last line, maybe you have to flip your kernel, because Matlab does a cross-correlation and call it convolution, also I'm not sure if you have to shift T before convolution or not `T = fftshift(T);`

```
clc
clear all
close all
%-----------------------------
I=imread('cameraman.tif');
f=fft2(I);
F=fftshift(f);
%-----------------------------
p = 2;
[r,c] = size(I);
% #xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
% T = zeros(r,c);
% for u = 1:r
%     for v = 1:c
%         T(u,v) = (u^2+v^2)^(p/2);
%     end
% end
% xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
u = 1:r;
v = 1:c;
[U,V] = meshgrid(u,v);
T = (U.^2 + V.^2)^(p/2);
F2 = conv2(F,T);
```

Comment: If kernel is symmetric then convolution equal cross-correlation. It is enough to multiply a quarter of the FFT and use symmetry (FFT from the real signal) to find the full matrix. Not use for...end, use meshgrid(). English is not my native language, so please be kind to my mistakes.

Comment: @Belal thank you, but I am trying to get high frequency information of image but I can not. Can you tell me how it can be achieved. The method is working a bit but not correctly.

Comment: @liwei if you want only the high-frequency information of an image, then you apply high pass filter HPF in the frequency domain, but your question seems to be different now!

Comment: @AlexAlex is this what you mean by taking a quarter of the FFT, and I have to flip at this point, right? because one quarter isn't symmetric as the whole FFT right? `Fquarter = f(1:ceil(r/2),1:ceil(c/2));
Flipped_Fquarter  = flip(Fquarter,2);
F2 = conv2(Fquarter,T);`

Comment: Something like this Fq=(U.*U+V.*V).^(p/2), size U and V is  r/2 x c/2. [U, V]=meshgrid(r/2, c/2); 
F=[Fq, fliplr(Fq); flipud(Fq), flipud(fliplr(Fq))]; Note that for an even and odd number of rows or columns, there will be a difference of one row or column.

Comment: @AlexAlex if the dimensions of the image are not even, I used `ceil` to consider the extra 1 line, and row in case of odd dimensions, also I tried `F=[Fq, fliplr(Fq); flipud(Fq), flipud(fliplr(Fq))];` it generated the following error: `Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.`

Comment: Thank you for the help, sorry for late reply...the answers get me going roughly